# How to match any parameter combination in a URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock.js

I am trying to simulate the response to this API URL

```
http://api.myapihost.com/images?foo=bar&spam=egg
```

The URL parameter combinations can vary. I am trying to intercept this request and respond with an empty object.

```
nock('http://api.myapihost.com')
  .persist()
  .get('/images', '*')
  .reply(200, {});
```

I get this error message when my test case runs:

```
Uncaught Error: Nock: No match for HTTP request GET /images?height=2500
```

How can I configure nock to match any combination of URL parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use path filtering in order to match the URL parameters.

```
var scope = nock('http://api.myapihost.com')
                .filteringPath(function(path) {
                   return '/images';
                 })
                .get('/images')
                .reply(200,  {});
```

You could check the docs [here](https://github.com/pgte/nock#path-filtering)

Comment: I had misread the documentation: I thought that changed the incoming request itself, not just the matching filter. Thanks for pointing out its correct use in a case like this.

Answer (score 44):

With [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) you can [specify regular expressions](https://github.com/node-nock/nock/tree/v9.2.3#specifying-path).

Here is an example (tested with v9.2.3):

```
nock('http://api.myapihost.com')
  .get(/images.*$/)
  .reply(200, {});
```

There is also a simpler syntax using `.query(true)`, if you want to mock the entire url regardless of the passed query string:

```
nock('http://api.myapihost.com')
  .get('/images')
  .query(true)
  .reply(200, {});
```